# How to remove unwanted alert on my site?

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm using a chat script which auto refreshes the chat-box every X seconds. The problem is, if I have a temporary downtime in the same time of the refresh, I get an alert such as: https://image.prntscr.com/image/Skig2-LMTkuCfPeCZiqT_A.jpeg

I think the source of the problem is inside this file: https://sbenny.com/forums/chat/assets/js/jchat.js
but for some reasons I'm unable to find it.

Is there a way to disable all the alerts on the site to prevent this problem to occur, if we're unable to find the function causing it?

I read this could help:

```
window.alert = function() {};
```

If so, is there any specific places I should place it or it's not relevant?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just place it before you load the jchat.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable most of the `alert` messages by either removing the `debug` option inside your chat header file or by uncheck the debug options in your phpBB if there is any.

If that doesn't help, just set `window.alert = function() {};` before you load your jchat.js file.

You can test it by immediately calling `alert( 'test' );`

```js
window.alert = function() {
   try { console.log( 'alert prevented' ) } catch ( e ) {}
}
alert( 'test' );
```

Comment: Debug is already disabled in both the chat header (no need to remove as it's disabled and I can confirm it by viewing the page source) and the phpbb script.

Comment: What happens if you set it to `debug: false` instead? It shouldn't make any difference though

Comment: The "debug" setting is already not called at all, since the <!-- IF S_CHAT_DEBUG --> statement is not true. The page source doesn't show the debug option at all indeed.

Comment: I know, but what if you explicitly set it to `debug: false`?

Comment: I'll try that as well. Any tips about checking if it works or not immediately? Since error 520 happens quite rarely, about 3 times every day and lasts a few seconds.

Comment: Add an `alert( 'test' )` after you changed it. You could also use the `window.alert` function from my edited answer, so you can see in you dev console, if it has been fired.

Comment: Thank you. As expected, setting debug: false didn't work. I'll now stick with the window.alert = function() {}; for a few days. If the alert will not appear anymore, I'll mark your answer as best answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Worked as a charm. Thanks!